# Is it too late for Son of a Nutcracker?

Tags: achievements, spiral-knights

Whenever my tier 2 character tries to join a lockdown game, it seemingly will take place on Reactor. While kind of fun, it has no snowballs.

Is it too late to get that achievement? Is my tier too high? Have I just been unlucky?

Answer (score 4):

It is not too late.  All of the listed daily achievements can be completed all the way up to January 1st (With the exception, of course, of achievements that list a specific date as a requirement).  You can even see a list of previous achievements (by the words "It's not too late!") in steam.

To clarify based on the other answer's comment thread, I can vouch that in the specific case of Son of a Nutcracker, the map is still in rotation as of this morning.  If you haven't gotten it yet, keep trying!

Comment: That's not generally true. The Defcon achievement can only be gotten on December 24th, unless you change the date on your computer. Something you can't do for MMOs.

Comment: @badp heh, fair enough.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @badp That's incorrect about the Defcon achievement - I completed that on the 21st, when the achievement was officially unveiled.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the in-game achievements exist independently of the Steam sale. So, it *is* still possible to get. Whether Steam still rewards you, I don't know.

I know I got that achievement late and several others early, so I would say you've just been unlucky so far.

Comment: Yes, which means the map with snowballs might've already been taken out from the pool of available maps. That's the whole point of my question.

Comment: The achievement was there *before* the sale. Why would it have been there if it were impossible to get? Is that just how Steam does things?

Comment: I just barely got that particular achievement a few hours ago on one of my alt accounts, so if that's all the question is about, that particular achievement, then you don't have anything to worry about.